# Unable to invoke action 'undefined': no controller and/or function found

Tags: visualforce, javascript, javascript-remoting, javascript-controller

Im trying to call a controller from my external js file, and im getting the title error, have you guys seen anything like this?

Page:

```
<apex:page controller="TestController" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <script>
            window.configSettings = {
                remoteActions: {
                    helloWorld: '{!$RemoteAction.TestController.helloWorld}'
                }
           }
        </script>
        <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.testJs}" loadOnReady="true"/>
    </head>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
public class TestController {
@ReadOnly
@RemoteAction
public static String helloWorld(){
    return 'hello world';
}
}
```

Javascript:

```
(function (window){
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
    window.configSettings.helloWorld,
    function(result, event){
        console.log(result);
    },
    {buffer: true, escape: true}
);
})(window);
```

Answer (score 2):

Well my dudes, it turns out im really stupid haha, i was trying to access the function without passing its property name, like window.configSettings.helloWorld, what i should be doing (which actually works perfectly) is calling it like window.configSettings.remoteActions.helloWorld

¯\_(ツ)_/¯